# master-slave MySQL replication with special characters in column name?

Tags: mysql, replication

I am trying to get a simple master-slave MySQL replication running, but I have some strange errors when LOAD DATA INFILE is used:

```
110908 23:59:42 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Unknown column 'NÂ°_Site' in 'field list'' on query. Default database: 'b4_sites'. Query: 'LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/SQL_LOAD-116-4-6441.data' IGNORE INTO  TABLE `cellule_1` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES  (`Region`, `V2G3G`, `Lac`, `CI`, `bsc_rnc`, `N°_Site`, `Constructeur`)', Error_code: 1054
110908 23:59:42 [Warning] Slave: Unknown column 'NÂ°_Site' in 'field list' Error_code: 1054
110908 23:59:42 [ERROR] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log 'mysql-bin.000002' position 68303896
```

We have *Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS* running on both master and slave .
Identical MySQL versions *mysql-server-core-5.1 - 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10* .
Almost identical MySQL configs (which I can post if needed) with nothing very fancy .

I can see that there is a special character in the name of one of the fields of the table which obviously provokes the error, but the strange thing is that the query is executed without error on the master...

The character sets on both servers - master:

```
mysql> show variables like "char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

slave:

```
mysql>  show variables like "char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help is welcome,
Thanks in advance

Comment: And does DESC b4_sites.cellule_1 produce the same output on both machinse?

Comment: Hello, yes, they are the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set=UTF8
...
```

,on the masters. Just the client section...

Or:

```
 mysql> SET NAMES UTF8;
```

So, just the names of the fields are in UTF-8.